# I can't translate the text <Any> in a form select list

Tags: i18n-l10n

I just can't translate the text  in a form select list.
I need it to be translated in spanish lang.
I tried to translate it using the translate interface but I couldn't find it.
Please take a look a the capture:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a problem translating strings with "<" and ">" in them, which is odd, but anyway:

http://drupal.org/node/348130
http://drupal.org/node/663156

If it's a [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) related problem, at `admin/build/views/tools` you can change **Label for "Any" value on optional single-select exposed filters:** to *- Any -* (instead of *<Any>*) and translate that.

Comment: As you said it was a Views related problem which I solved at admin/build/views/tools. Thanks!